# CSV data ingestion in Solr issue

Tags: csv, hadoop, solr, data-ingestion

I am new to Solr and trying to ingest CSV file to a demo collection. Below is the command I am trying to execute.

```
 [solr@ambari solr]$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/fbdemo_shard1_replica1/update/csv 
--data-binary /tmp/solrdata/331076060277979_facebook_comments_korek.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

Bellow is the repsonse I get but no data is ingested. Appreciate your help. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">4</int></lst>
</response>
```

Comment: this is the response <response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">4</int></lst>

Comment: add ?commit=true to the url. If not enough, do you see any errors in the log?

Comment: Thanks for replying. found the issue. you have put @ before the acutal csv file. silly me